# Threadpoolsize of ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a ScheduledExecutorService that gets tasks for periodically execution:

```
scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool( what size? );

public addTask(ScheduledFuture<?> myTask, delay, interval) {
    myTask = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
          // doing work here
     },
          delay,
          interval,
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
}
```

The number of tasks the scheduler gets depends solely on the user of my program. Normaly it should be a good idea, afaik, to make the ThreadPoolSize #number_of_Cpu_Threads, so that each CPU or CPU Thread executes one Task at a time, cause this should give the fastest throughput. But what should i do if the Tasks involve I/O (as they do in my program)? The tasks in my program are grabbing data from a server on the internet and saving them in a db. So that means most of the time they are waiting for the data to come in (aka idle). So what would be the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the exact context:

- How many tasks will be added? (You've said it's up to the user, but do you have *any* idea? Do you know this before you need to create the pool?)
- How long does each of them take?
- Will they be doing *any* intensive work?
- If they're all saving to the same database, is there any concurrency issue there? (Perhaps you want to have several threads fetching from different servers and putting items in a queue, but only one thread actually storing data in the database?)
- So long as you don't get "behind", how important is the performance anyway?

Ultimately I strongly suspect you'll need to benchmark this yourself - it's impossible to give general guidance without more information, and even with specific numbers it would be mostly guesswork. Hard data is much more useful :)

Note that the argument to `newScheduledThreadPool` only specifies the number of *core* threads to keep in the thread pool if threads are idle - so it's going to be doing a certain amount of balancing itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It's basically a program to get stockPrices. The user can create a stock and then the price of that stock will be grabbed over the internet every xx minutes and saved in a db. So the more stocks the user adds the more tasks the scheduler gets (one for every stock). So i don't really have any idea cause it depends on how many stocks the user adds (will probably install a limit of a hundred or so). Already anticipated there is no general answer, will test then and probably doing something like #number_of_Cpu_Threads * basic number.

Comment: @BieneMaja: Are you getting the stocks from the same web service (or whatever)? If so, does the web service not have a bulk fetch (so you can specify all the stocks in one call)? Even if not, why not just schedule *one* task which iterates over all the stocks? This doesn't feel like a good fit for "lots of tasks" to me.

Comment: The are multiple web servies, i only have 1 implemented currently though. The thinking behind many tasks insted of 1 was more flexibilty. The user can create and delete stocks. So before a stock is deleted i have to cancel the task that uses it, cause otherwise it would collide (trying to delete a stock while updating it). So if i had one task for all i had to cancel the task and thus the other stocks won't be updated and i had to start the task again after deleting is done. That's at least what i am thinking as im completly new to thread programming.